# How to: 1 Webpack for all project with importing lib from node_modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, resolve, webpack-5

```js
// Project Tree View: My idea about using Webpack.

+ Toolkit:
  - D:/Toolkit/Webpack/webpack.config.js

+ Project:
  - D:/Project/A/build/index.ts
  - D:/Project/B/build/index.ts
  - D:/Project/C/build/index.ts
```

```js
// Toolkit: [webpack.config.js] file

const path = require('path');
module.exports = (env) => {

    let project_root = env.path;

    console.log(env);
    console.log(__dirname);

    return {
        mode: env.mode,
        entry: project_root+'/build/index.ts',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    use: 'ts-loader',
                    include: [
                        path.resolve(project_root, 'build'),
                        path.resolve('./node_modules'),
                    ]
                }, {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    use: [
                        "style-loader",
                        "css-loader",
                        "sass-loader",
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: 'public',
            filename: 'script.js',
            path: path.resolve(project_root, 'assets/js')
        },
        resolve: {
            modules: ['node_modules'],
        },
    }
}
```

#### Build command: `yarn build --env=path=D:/Project/C`

The command works without error, but when importing any library from the **node_modules**

Ex:

```
import {lib} from "example_lib";
import {lib} from "~example_lib";
import {lib} from "@example_lib";
import {lib} from "node_modules/example_lib";
import {lib} from "./node_modules/example_lib";
```

## The Error

```
ERROR in ../A/build/index.ts 1:0-52
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'example_lib' in 'D:\Project\A'
resolve 'example_lib' in 'D:\Project\A'
  Parsed request is a module
  No description file found in D:\Project\A\build or above
  resolve as module
    D:\Project\A\build\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
    ...
    D:\node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory

ERROR in D:\Project\A\build\index.ts
../A/build/index.ts 1:20-49
[tsl] ERROR in D:\Project\A\build\index.ts(1,21)
      TS2792: Cannot find module 'example_lib'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?

webpack 5.26.2 compiled with 2 errors in 1939 ms
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

## The Question is:

- How to use **ONLY 1** Webpack **node_modules** for all projects ?

> [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com) can resolve this issue but how about [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org) ?

> I do not want every project to have 1 node_modules or webpack, package,... inside (it trash my PC !)

[image: node_modules]

Answer (score 0):

- The issue has been resolved !
- The above code is correct.
- Format ".js" works normally; however ".ts" need to add `// @ts-ignore` above every import external node_modules.

### This is the answer !

```
// @ts-ignore
import {lib} from "example_lib";
```

---

#### **NOTE:** 7 days researching Webpack

> This is my opinions:
> Gulp is much more than Webpack even it has lower user
>
> These are the Pros about Gulp that Webpack should have !

- Less time for controlling the core.
- User-friendly.
- Clear and Clean Structure, less bracket.
- Easy and Flexible for creating the custom config.
- Easy to use, develop through time.
- Not just for web field, on the backup data, auto,... as well.
- 1 node_modules for all external projects (Gulp less bug and coding line than Webpack).
- Compile time are the same.

## Gulp is the King  !